# Comparing ICCs between logistic and linear mixed-effects models

Tags: mixed-model, model-evaluation, intraclass-correlation, brms

I have a (Bayesian) logistic mixed-effects model and a linear one, both fitted with brms. Both are fitted on data from human subjects that account for repetition, therefore, I have included a subject identifier as a random effect.

Now, what I would like to quantify is how much the subject factor matters in the model, and compare the logistic and linear model. For instance, I would like to answer the question of whether the subject mattered more in the logistic than in the linear model, i.e., is the logistic model more individual-dependent/subjective than the linear one. Can I infer this information with ICC (intra-class correlation) coefficients and how cautious do I have to be about the type (logistic vs linear)? I have calculated ICCs with the icc function from the performance R package (https://rdrr.io/cran/performance/man/icc.html). However, it seems like the equations are different between logistic and linear models.